# Does folder deleted when updating Android App on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play

I am newbie in developing Android app.
I am going to publish the app to Google Play Store soon, but I have one quick question.
Currently my app have the feature to create the image folder under my app package name and store all the images.
When I publish the new version of the app with updating in Google Play Store, does the image folder under that package name is deleted?

Thanks,

Comment: No it will be there

Comment: Folders associated with the app are deleted upon uninstall, not update. Unless there is a specific reason to put the photos in the app folder I would put them in the standard album so the user can delete or retrieve them at their convenience.

Comment: What do you mean by not update?

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to publish an app in Android Market make sure you perform all these tests and doubts that you have in your mind. In addition, files, won't be deleted it'll stay as Residual files maybe even after uninstalling.

Answer (score 0):

Folders associated with the app are deleted upon uninstall, not update.